# WP7 Localising DatePicker control form caption

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, datepicker, timepicker

With  the DatePicker and TimePicker controls, the default is that upon being selected, they will bring up their own page to allow entry/updating of the date.

This Page has a caption of 'CHOOSE DATE" or "CHOOSE TIME".

I am altering an app to support another language, and  this is the last task I have to do.
There  does not seem to be an easy way be able to update these captions.

I have found [this](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7266) from some time ago.  Aside from this I have not found anything else?

I am surprised it is not a property on the control itself to make it straightforward.

Comment: Could you use ToLocalTime() or ToUniversalTime() when you set the value on the datetime picker, or getting the value. DateTime kind provides information about current localization of DateTime

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do this is by changing the source code.

Look this => http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7266